# How to keep openvpn connection open on Centos

Tags: linux, centos, vpn, openvpn, centos7

I access test server via shell and i use this command to connect to VPN

```
sudo openvpn client.conf
```

I want to keep the connection open with the VPN,

something like service when you make service start

```
sudo service httpd start
```

Beause when the i close the shell the connection is closed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `nohup` and wrap your command in backticks

```
nohup `sudo openvpn client.conf`
```

Comment: Works like charm

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed OpenVPN via an RPM or DEB package on Linux, the installer will have set up an initscript so that OpenVPN is started on startup.

When executed, the initscript will scan for .conf configuration files in /etc/openvpn, and if found, will start up a separate OpenVPN daemon for each file.

If you do not want this to happen at startup just remove OpenVPN from startup and still put the config file in /etc/openvpn . Then when you want to start openvpn just run:

/etc/init.d/openvpn start

The daemon will then find the config file and openvpn will remain started.

Hope this helps!